# legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy, тонкости использования

Tags: c#, .net

1) Что конкретно делает `legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy`?

Кроме слов о возврате среды CLR к поведению версий 1.0 и 1.1 в документации ничего не нашел. Что это конкретно за поведение?

2) Как быть если есть приложение, которое грузит в отдельный `AddDomain` сборку (управляемую .dll), и исключение происходит в ней. Включение опции `legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy` в этом случае нужно указывать в файл `.config` для сборки или достаточно указать для приложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В документации чёрным по белому написано, что включение этого флага отключает изменения, перечисленные в [Change from Previous Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228965.aspx#ChangeFromPreviousVersions).

> The most significant change pertains to managed threads. In the .NET Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1, the common language runtime provides a backstop for unhandled exceptions in the following situations:
>
> - There is no such thing as an **unhandled exception on a thread pool thread**. When a task throws an exception that it does not handle, the runtime prints the exception stack trace to the console and then returns the thread to the thread pool.
> - There is no such thing as an **unhandled exception on a thread created with the Start method of the Thread class**. When code running on such a thread throws an exception that it does not handle, the runtime prints the exception stack trace to the console and then gracefully terminates the thread.
> - There is no such thing as an **unhandled exception on the finalizer thread**. When a finalizer throws an exception that it does not handle, the runtime prints the exception stack trace to the console and then allows the finalizer thread to resume running finalizers.
>
> The foreground or background status of a managed thread does not affect this behavior.
>
> For unhandled exceptions on threads originating in unmanaged code, the difference is more subtle. The runtime JIT-attach dialog preempts the operating system dialog for managed exceptions or native exceptions on threads that have passed through native code. The process terminates in all cases.

В целом, старое поведение прятало исключения в потоках из пула, созданных вручную потоках и потоке финализатора: вместо выкидывания неотловленного исключения оно молча писалось в консоль, и рантайм делал вид, что ничего не было.

Этот флаг не следует использовать **никогда**. Это исключительно костыль для ископаемых библиотек, написаных во времена зарождения дотнета, которые полагаются на вышеописанное поведение. В других случаях флаг никаким образом не поможет, потому что исключения всё равно будут рушить потоки, и приложение просто перестанет функционировать. Что касается старого кода, то если у библиотеки 13 лет не было обновлений, я бы всерьёз задумался, а стоит ли использовать такую библиотеку. Скорее всего, не стоит.

> Как быть если есть приложение, которое грузит в отдельный AddDomain сборку (управляемую .dll), и исключение происходит в ней.

В идеале следует сделать так, чтобы непойманных исключений не было. Можно обрабатывать unhandled exception'ы разных сортов (на правах грязного хака). Можно позволить домену обрушиться и загрузить сборку заново. Магические флаги вам не помогут.